# Existe alguma forma de usar um "custom-attribute" como valor de uma propriedade CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de usar um `custom-attribute` do tipo `data-*=" "` como valor para um estilo CSS ou mesmo usar esse *custom* *data* como valor para uma variável no CSS.

Para exemplificar melhor vou explicar minha ideia. Eu gostaria de colocar no elemento tipo `<div data-opacity="0.5" ></div>` e essa `div` ficar com 0.5 de opacidade. Logo eu preciso que de alguma forma o CSS reconheça esse valor de 0.5 do `data-opacity` como o valor do `opacity:` na classe

Eu tentei usar o `attr` direto como valor do estilo `opacity: attr(data-opacity)` e também tentei declarar como variável, porém tb não deu certo `--data-opacity: attr(data-opacity)`

*Esse é só um exemplo de uso, mas poderia ser para cor, margens, etc* Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de usar esse `custom-attribute` como valor dentro do CSS?

Segue um exemplo do que eu gostaria de fazer, porém não funciona como está.

```css
:root {
    --data-opacity: attr(data-opacity);
    --cor: #fff;
}

[data-opacity] {
    color: var(--cor);
    opacity: var(--data-opacity); /* não funciona */
    /* opacity: attr(data-opacity); */ /* também não funciona */
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-opacity="0.5">cor branca mas sem opacidade</div>
```

Comment: Até faria uma versão em `js` mas creio que logo aparecera uma versão apenas com `CSS`, rs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O CSS consegue acessar os valores de custom attributes como os `data-*` através do método `attr()`, o problema é que ele sempre será interpretado como uma string, o que pode ter alguma utilidade, porém acaba invalidando a atribuição à maioria das propriedades da folha de estilo.

Segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/attr) a tipagem e o suporte a outras propriedades que não o `content` é apenas experimental.

**Exemplo:**

```css
h1 {
  /* Não funciona, pois seria o mesmo que declarar color:'red';*/
  color: attr(data-cor);
}

h1::before {
  /* Funciona, porque content está esperando uma string. */
  content: attr(data-prefixo);
}
```

```html
<h1 data-prefixo="Olar, " data-cor="red">meu nome não é johnny.</h1>
```

**Alternativa**

Uma possibilidade é utilizar uma declaração inline dessas variáveis através do atributo `style` e da função `var()`, preservando assim a tipagem e a validação dos valores apresentados para a aplicação do estilo.

```css
:root {
  --opacidade: 1;
  --cor: #ffff;
}

.box {
  color: var(--cor);
  opacity: var(--opacidade);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">apenas valores iniciais</div>
<div class="box" style="--cor:yellow">cor amarela mas sem opacidade</div>
<div class="box" style="--cor:yellow; --opacidade: 0.5;">cor amarela com opacidade</div>
```

**Mas se é para escrever no `style`, não é a mesma coisa que definir toda a aparência ali mesmo e ignorar a folha de estilos?**

Na prática é quase a mesma coisa, porém existem algumas vantagens, considerando o cenário onde você deseja fazer o devido tratamento de compatibilidade para diversos browsers e ainda quiser aproveitar o fallback da função `var()`. É possível concentrar todas as variações no seu CSS e ainda determinar valores default para cada um.

```css
h1 {
  color: var(--minha-cor, grey);
  -webkit-filter: blur(var(--meu-blur, none));
  -moz-filter: blur(var(--meu-blur, none));
  -ms-filter: blur(var(--meu-blur, none));
  -o-filter: blur(var(--meu-blur, none));
  filter: blur(var(--meu-blur, none));
}
```

```html
<h1 style="--minha-cor: green; --meu-blur: 1px">
  verde com blur
</h1>
<h1 style="--minha-cor: blue; --meu-blur: 2px">
  azul com mais com blur
</h1>
<h1>
  default
</h1>
```

Comment: Gostei da resposta. :)

Comment: É isso ai, acho que seria a melhor abordagem

Comment: @hugocsl e aguardar o release do draft https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#attr-notation