# Classe dinâmica em Stylus

Tags: stylus

É possivel recuperar uma parte do nome de uma classe em um elemento e passar como valor para a propriedade do CSS utilizand Stylus?
Exemplo

```
.font-word-spacing-light--1 {
  word-spacing: -0.1px !important
}
.font-letter-spacing-light--1 {
  letter-spacing: -0.1px !important
}
.align-left--16px {
  position relative
  left -16px
}
```

E neste caso, utilizar no elemento da seguinte forma

```
<h2 class="font-word-spacing-light--1 font-letter-spacing-light--1 align-left--16px">Elemento</h2>
```

Neste caso, queria saber se isso é possível, como o vuetify faz algo assim, fiquei imaginando se é possível, lá tem por exemplo as classes de cores

```
cor-vermelha /* cor de fundo vermelha */
cor-vermelha--text /* cor da fonte vermelha */
```

Eu li no manual que existem Mixins, Variáveis e Funções só não entendi direito como utilizar e se possibilita o que mencionei

---

Vamos dizer que algo prático ficaria assim (estou apenas exemplificando com uma sintaxe qualquer)

```
<h2 class="cor-do-texto--ff00ff tamanho-do-texto--60">
  Título com cor #ff00ff e tamanho 60PX
</h2>

<style lang="stylus">
  .cor-do-texto--{%s}
    color #{%s} /* imprime color: #ff00ff */

  .tamanho-do-texto--{%s}
    text-size {%s}PX /* imprime text-size: 60px */
</style>
```

> resolução caso alguém chegue aqui com a mesma dúvida

```
maxkw = 7680

width(n)
  width n !important

min-width(n)
  min-width n !important

max-width(n)
  max-width n !important

.width
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-{r}
      width(1px * r)
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-v-{r}
      width(1vw * r)
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-per-{r}
      width(1% * r)

.min-width
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-{r}
      min-width(1px * r)
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-v-{r}
      min-width(1vw * r)
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-per-{r}
      min-width(1% * r)

.max-width
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-{r}
      max-width(1px * r)
  for r in 0..maxk
    &-v-{r}
      max-width(1vw * r)
  for r in 0..maxkw
    &-per-{r}
      max-width(1% * r)


maxkh = 4320

height(n)
  height n !important

min-height(n)
  min-height n !important

max-height(n)
  max-height n !important

.height
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-{r}
      height(1px * r)
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-v-{r}
      height(1vh * r)
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-per-{r}
      height(1% * r)

.min-height
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-{r}
      min-height(1px * r)
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-v-{r}
      min-height(1vh * r)
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-per-{r}
      min-height(1% * r)

.max-height
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-{r}
      max-height(1px * r)
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-v-{r}
      max-height(1vh * r)
  for r in 0..maxkh
    &-per-{r}
      max-height(1% * r)
```

Comment: Não é possível, o propósito do Stylus não é esse. Você teria que ter uma classe para cada item que quer estilizar, pois o código precisa ser processado para virar CSS. **Nesse caso**, acho que é mais vantajoso alternar as propriedades do elemento diretamente com JS.

Comment: @Renan entendi, imaginei, que pena que as functions não funcionam assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu já havia deixado isso de lado, até que hoje eu descobri apenas por acidente por ter entendido outro fator do stylus, ointerpolation com parametros, bom, logo descobri que posso fazer desta forma

```
  width(n)
    width n !important

  .width
    for row in 0..999999
      &-{row}
        width(1px * row)
    &-half
      width 50%
    &-full
      width 100%
```

e ao criar um elemento com a classe

```
<div class="width-100"/>
```

este terá 100 pixels ou qualquer quantidade até no máximo 999999, pode ser mais, mas não vejo motivo para width

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas acho que é isso que vc precisa. Se vc tem uma `variável` que contem uma `cor`, vc pode incluir essa cor na propriedade, como abaixo.

**Se vc tem esse Stylus**

```
vermelha = red

.cor-vermelha 
    background vermelha

.cor-vermelha--text
    color vermelha
```

**Output do CSS**

```
.cor-vermelha {
    background: red;
}

.cor-vermelha--text {
    color: red;
}
```

**OBS:** o detalhe é que com o código acima vc vai ter a cor do texto igual a do fundo e vc não veria o texto pq os dois estão da mesma cor...

HTML

```
<h2 class="cor-vermelha cor-vermelha--text">Elemento</h2>
```

Comment: olá, no caso, é quase isso porém a cor vermelha é só exemplo, o que eu queria é não ter que prédeterminar a cor vermelha, exemplo .cor--red então o stylus coloca red na var $vermelha ou vamos supor que eu envie cor-do-texto--ff0000 então ele coloca o ff0000 na variavel e a classe obtem esta variável como algo .cor-do-texto^ff0000

Comment: @flourigh vc quer usar um nome de classe que não existe, por exemplo cor-fff e quer que o Browser de alguma forma identifique esse -fff e coloque a cor do texto branco? Isso não é possível! Acho que o mais próximo que vc vai conseguir é isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330390/existe-alguma-forma-de-usar-um-custom-attribute-como-valor-de-uma-propriedade

Comment: seria basicamente isso mesmo, ele indentificar a classe e pegar o que está depois de -- como se fosse uma variável como o vuetify faz quando usamos cor-que-eu-quero--text

Comment: @flourigh então a resposta no momento acredito que não seja possível! Nem som Stylus, ou SASS, pois do HTML vc não consegue mudar uma classe que esteja no seu .CSS, a não ser como nas opções do link que te passei, Mas como esses pré-processadores vc não consegue mudar o valor da variável a partir do `style` no HTML.

Comment: entendi, achei que fosse possível por causa do manual deixar a entender as variáveis porém não entendi perfeitamente como as utilizar, irei ler mais um pouco, agradeço

Comment: @flourigh tem como me passar o link de onde vc viu essa possibilidade?

Comment: não vi esta possibilidade explicita mas vi algumas classes no vuetify que pareciam dar esta possibilidade e vasculhando o manual do stylus, vi algumas coisas como estas http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#lookupname & http://stylus-lang.com/docs/vargs.html & http://stylus-lang.com/docs/hashes.html#getters que pareciam dar a possibilidade

Comment: @flourigh todos esses exemplos são construídos no Stylus e depois compilados para o CSS, não tem nada falando que vc pode alterar o nome da classe no HTML e ele altera o valor da propriedade no CSS. O que pode acontecer e vc configurar algum WebPack da vida para tratar esse tipos de coisa, ai na hora de subir o projeto ele pega a última string do nome da classe e cria uma variável no Stylus com esse valor e seta no elemento, algo bem complexo, mas que aconteceria na compilação e não "nativamente" escrevendo HTML/CSS. Isso `margin(n)` ou `opacity(n)` deve ser feito no Stylus/CSS, não no HTML

Comment: realmente, estou utilizando Vue.js & vuex & vuetify & stylus, da para fazer com o vue mas queria ver se é possivel com stylus, obrigado