# Como definir um meta theme-color em runtime a partir dos estilos da aplicação

Tags: html, css, react, sass

Estou desenvolvendo um web app baseado em React que utiliza [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react) (que por sua vez utiliza Sass) e preciso que a cor da barra do navegador (definida via html meta, conforme mostra o código a seguir) seja obtida a partir do estilo da aplicação (definido no arquivo `_vars.scss` como `$c-primary-light: #303E2F;`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="var($c-primary-light)"/>
</head>
</html>
```

Definir manualmente a cor no HTML não é uma opção viável, pois a aplicação é do tipo multi tenant, onde cada domínio tem cores diferentes.

Em minhas abordagens (código anterior), tentei obter a cor a partir da variável CSS diretamente no HTML, contudo acredito que isso não é possível.

Quais as possíveis abordagens para solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Cara não sei se sua lógica está correta... Não entendo de React, mas como vc quer pegar uma Variavel Sass no HTML, jogar para o Sass, compilar o CSS e depois entregar o página renderizada... Isso está meio confuso de entender... Mesmo está no head da página vc teria que compilar a Sass com a cor nova e devolver o CSS antes da pagina terminar o paint....

Comment: Basicamente meu problema é definir o `theme-color` de acordo com um estilo selecionado em runtime - e minha preferência é "buscar" essa cor nas variáveis do Sass. Se isso não for possível, gostaria de sugestões para implementar isso usando outros meios.

Comment: O que tenho visto mais atualmente é o uso do CSS Variables com as cores, apenas pelo simples fato de já ser CSS e não precisar compilar, e assim o override é mais fácil... Se quiser posso colocar uma resposta sobre o assunto, só não sei se vai ser 100% aplicável no seu caso. Talvez isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298995/o-que-significa-o-especificado-no-root-do-css-do-bootstrap/298998#298998 e isso possam te dar uma luz https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330390/existe-alguma-forma-de-usar-um-custom-attribute-como-valor-de-uma-propriedade

Comment: Os links ajudam, sim. Acredito que será preciso criar um script para resolver o valor da variável CSS e então atualizar o theme-color, tudo via javascript. Ainda não sei exatamente como fazer isso. Com relação à resposta, ficarei feliz em marcá-la como solução enquanto for a contribuição mais relevante para resolução do problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da discussão nos comentários da pergunta, e da [resposta do hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/373261/7499), "liguei os pontos" e encontrei uma solução para meu problema. Descrevo aqui o que seria um complemento à resposta do Hugo, porém específico para a situação que descrevi na pergunta.

Após declarar a variável personalizada (`_vars.scss` => `$c-primary: #303E2F;`), incluo a mesma no selector `:root` do App:

```
@import "vars";

:root {
  --meta-theme-color: #{$c-primary};
}
```

O `#{ $variavel }` é necessário para resolver o valor da variável nesse momento, como notado [nesta issue do GitHub](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1943#issuecomment-379747451) (em inglês).

Então, no javascript (utilizei o `index.js`), crio a tag meta com a cor obtida do estilo:

```js
const themeColor = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(':root')).getPropertyValue('--meta-theme-color').trim();
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = 'theme-color';
meta.content = themeColor;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

---

Bônus: [este artigo](https://medium.com/collabcode/como-manipular-o-head-das-p%C3%A1ginas-react-utilizando-o-react-helmet-da-nfl-c10481a74782) me ajudou a desenvolver a solução e apresentou uma biblioteca chamada [Header](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet), que facilita a atualização dinâmica da head.

Comment: Bacana o artigo, legal que resolveu ai

Answer (score 1):

Vou te dar umas dicas que pode te ajudar nisso.

Primeiro tenha em mente que mesmo dentro do seu SASS vc pode ter Custom Variables do padrão CSS normal.

Por exemplo vc pode ter no seu `color.scss` variáveis dos dois tipos. Então o código abaixo vai compilar normalmente!

```
/* variável SASS padrão */
$color-fff: #fff;

/* variável CSS padrão */
:root {
    --vermelho: #f00;
    --azul: #00f;
}
body {
    background-color: var(--vermelho);
}
p{
    color: $color-fff; 
}
```

Agora vc pode fazer o *override* dos `--var()` tranquilamente direto no HTML, seja incluindo uma nova folha de estilo.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="color.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="override-da-cor.css">
</head>
```

Ou simplesmente incluindo um tag `<style>` dentro do `<head>` com o *override* da variável.

```
<head>
    <style>
    /* trocando direto no root a referencia para todas as ocorrências */
        :root {
            --azul: #0f0;
        }
        body {
            background-color: var(--azul);
        }
    /* ou trocando apenas no elemento que precisa */
        p {
            --azul: #000;
            color: var(--azul);
        }
    </style>
</head>
```